Jenkinsfile converting base64 keystore data into jks file prints secret data on console
I am working on a Jenkins CI/CD setup to build and sign android apps. keystore base64 data is stored in a secret vault(https://www.hashicorp.com/products/vault). To convert it into jks file I am running below command in JenkinsFile. The issue is its printing the entire key(visible under Jenkins console output section).
sh "echo ${keystore} | base64 --decode > android/app/keystore.jks"

Jenkins console output:

Is there any other way to convert it into jks file without exposing sensitive data in logs.

Can you show where keystore is coming from?

its fetched from vault and in vault its stored in base64 format. Above command is working as expected. only issue is it also prints the keystore base64 data on console.

basically its stored like a secret

Jenkins can mask sensitive information in logs, but you need to tell it it's sensitive. How do you retrieve the secret from the vault into the variable? Show me code.

I am using shared library code which is maintained by ci/cd team.
Method  structure
vaultImpl.getSecretByVaultViaNamespaces("")

Are you limited to standard Linux tools are couldn't you just develoe a small program that directly reads the keystore from ENV variable and saves it or directly performs the signing (the necessary Java library is available as Maven artifact).

Writing any custom program is a much more  serious limitation than sticking to any standard tools provided either by Linux or by Jenkins itself.

Given that you use Hashicorp Vault I assume that you use the corresponding Jenkins plugin which should handle the masking properly (as well as the credentials binding plugin that AFAIR allows to use Hashicorp Vault secrets).
But the main issue I see here is that you're using double quotes - that is explicitly discouraged by Jenkins documentation because of the security reasons:

Groovy string interpolation should never be used with credentials.

I suppose you might have a warning regarding that on you build results page.
You have to replace the double quotes with the single ones:
sh 'echo ${keystore} | base64 --decode > android/app/keystore.jks'

Also, an even safer option would be to bind the secret to an environment variable and printenv it instead of echoing.
